# excel, find last previous date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to get the next matched date from one column to the next.
So far I have tried getting the minimum of col F, `=MIN(F2:F60)` .
Now In another sheet in column D, I want to match this and if I cant match find the  closet previous date.

In the below my last date is 11-Sep-2018, So I want to look into another column and return 11-Sept-2018 or the closet previous date, which could be anything before sept 11.

[image]

dont mind the duplicates.

Comment: Is the list on the other page sorted ascending(oldest first)?

Comment: @ScottCraner other page is oldest  in D3, and then goes all the way  to 2018 in D249.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use VLOOKUP

```
=VLOOKUP(MIN(F2:F60),Sheet2!D:D,1,TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems obvious, but i NEVER use 'TRUE' here. I guess in this case it is handy.

Comment: This is exactly what TRUE was meant for.

Comment: YES TRUE MASTER